# different language on site and in cms with Django

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a German website built with Django. However, I would like the CMS backend to be English, while the configuration of the site should remain German for frontend. Is this possible in Django?
Using:
Django 1.3
Django-CMS 2.3

Comment: What have you tried in terms of Django internationalisation?: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Here is a code for middleware that will accomplish this (taken from http://source.mihelac.org/2009/11/12/django-set-language-for-admin/):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import translation


class AdminLocaleURLMiddleware:

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path.startswith('/admin'):
            request.LANG = getattr(settings, 'ADMIN_LANGUAGE_CODE', settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
            translation.activate(request.LANG)
            request.LANGUAGE_CODE = request.LANG
```